# C# TCP/IP Server showing as not connected

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

For some reason my server is showing as disconnected when the client seems to have at least connected to the open port and is sending packets down it.

```
 clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);


            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(PORT));

            //Bind and listen 
            clientSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            clientSocket.Listen(5);

            //Accept incoming 
            clientSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
```

Then after this here is my OnAccept method.

```
 private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket.EndAccept(ar);



            if (clientSocket.Connected == true)
            {
                clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), clientSocket);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Log(ex.ToString(), 2);
        }
    }
```

I am using an out of the box client to connect (something im using for testing purposes) however when I start a connection to listen and click "connect" on the client. The client turns to "Connected" state and starts to send packets. However that "if (clientSocket.Connected == true)" statement always fails, even after running a breakpoint on it so its not a timing issue.

Any help and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that when im using the async and listening in the way I am, I have to accept on that socket a new socket.

```
Socket clientSocket2 = clientSocket.EndAccept(ar);
```

Then gets the connection on cliientSocket2.